# A proof that If a right adjoint preserves injective then the left adjoint is exact?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I know that if a left adjoint is exact then the right adjoint preserves injectives.

For the converse, I read in "A QUICK PROOF OF THE GABRIEL-POPESCU THEOREM" of Mitchell that:

"a left adjoint whose codomain has enough injectives preserves monomorphisms if and only if its right adjoint preserves injectives".

So, in this case, the converse is true but I don't find any proof of this. Can someone help me?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The calculations (switching back and forth via the adjunction) are similar for both directions, so I will only provide a hint, since I guess you can take it from there.

Let $F \colon {\cal X} \to {\cal A} $ be left adjoint to $G \colon {\cal A} \to {\cal X} $, and let $ u \colon X \to Y $ be a monomorphism in ${\cal X}$.

(1) by assumption, we can embed $FX$ in some injective object $E$, i.e.  there is a monomorphism $h \colon FX \to E$. Let  $ \hat{h} \colon X \to GE $ be its adjoint.

(2) because $GE$ is injective, we can extend $\hat{h}$ along the monomorphism $u$.

(3) switch back via the adjunction to obtain a morphism $f \colon FY \to E$ with $h = f \circ Fu$ and conclude that $Fu$ must be monic.